# Shared URLSession vs URLSession with default configuration

Tags: ios, swift, macos

What is the difference between **Shared URLSession** and **URLSession with default configuration**?

In my app i was using **URLSession.shared** to send a request to server. Now i'm trying to change it to **URLSession.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)**.

But if i use **URLSession.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)** all my request are taking more time to load.

Compared to **URLSession.shared**, **URLSession.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)** is taking more time to load the request.(Shared Session is 5 to 10 time faster than URLSession with default Configuration).

What is the Difference between these two methods?

Why URLSession With Default Configuration is taking more to load the request?

Comment: Please share code - I am very skeptical that URLSessionConfiguration.default is slower

Answer (score 6):

## Limitations of the Shared Session

- You don’t provide a delegate or a configuration object.
- You can’t obtain data incrementally as it arrives from the server.
- You can’t significantly customize the default connection behavior.
- Your ability to perform authentication is limited.
- You can’t perform background downloads or uploads when your app isn’t running.

In other words, if you’re doing anything with caches, cookies, authentication, or custom networking protocols, you should probably be using a default session instead of the shared session.

For more info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1409000-shared

Answer (score 2):

URLSession has a singleton shared session (which has no configuration object) for basic requests. It’s not as customizable as sessions you create, but it serves as a good starting point if you have very limited requirements. URLSession.shared is already created object which no required extra time for configuration, and the issue is default value of default timeout

For me, one of the best practice is to create a shared instance of URLsession and use it for multiple tasks. No overhead configuration required because usually you need the same configuration for an api.
The benefit of this is that I had to create the session only once, so that will save repetition of same code and also the process to initialise the same thing again per api request. This will be more helpful in case you need to more custom configuration of the session.

Answer (score 2):

URLSession.init(): Implemented by subclasses to initialize a new object (the receiver) immediately after memory for it has been allocated.
 note that: An object isn’t ready to be used until it has been initialized.

URLSession.shared: For basic requests, the URLSession class provides a shared singleton session object that gives you a reasonable default behavior for creating tasks. Use the shared session to fetch the contents of a URL to memory with just a few lines of code.
Unlike the other session types, you don’t create the shared session; you merely access it by using this property directly. As a result, you don’t provide a delegate or a configuration object.